# Preserve space between words java

Tags: java

I have a method with two inputs. The problem is when I type something like fast car.When it returns the message after the calculations I will get idvwfdu it gets rid of the space between the two words, but I want idvw fdu. How can I fix that?

```
for (int i=0; i<text.length();i++){
       char c=text.charAt(i);
       char character=(char)(c+shift);

       if (character >='a' && character <='z'){

          newMsg+=character;

       }else if(character > 'z') {

          newMsg+=(char)((char)(c-(26-shift)));
       }


}

return newMsg;
```

Comment: add some `else if` for `' '`?

Comment: do you want to have same functionality for space as you have for `a-z` characters?

Comment: You only check for characters between a to z and characters greater than z. Space is less than a, and you are not checking for that. Look at an ASCII table to see what ASCII number is assigned to a space.

Comment: i tried the else if ' ' but i kept getting an error, that is invalid.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There are two issues with your code. First one is that you are shifting every character before checking like here

```
char character=(char)(c+shift); // you already lost space character here
```

and secondly you are losing the space here

```
if (character >='a' && character <='z'){

     newMsg+=character;

   }else if(character > 'z') { // space will be shifted once again

      newMsg+=(char)((char)(c-(26-shift)));
   }
```

So in order to fix this you have to keep both evaluation in mind and the result should look like this

```
String text = "fast car";
String newMsg = "";
int shift = 1;
for (int i = 0; i < text.length(); i++) {
      char c = text.charAt(i);
      char character = (char)(c != ' ' ? c + shift : c); // first space check

      if (character >= 'a' && character <= 'z') {

          newMsg += character;

      } else if (character == ' ') newMsg += ' '; // second space check
      else if (character > 'z') {

          newMsg += (char)((char)(c - (26 - shift)));
      }

System.out.println(newMsg); // prints gbtu dbs
```

Comment: Your answer would look so nice if you added brackets to that middle `if`...

Comment: @walen Ah, well that's my personal preference to keep one liner's if possible. But yeah I try not to do that in production code :D

Comment: @MuratK. I like to indulge myself with some one-liners now and then too :) Still, mixing different styles like in the above code (a bracketed `if`, followed by a non-bracketed `if` with the `else` in the same line as the previous closing bracket, followed by a, once again, bracketed `if` but with the `else` in the next line...) should come with an OCD warning sticker! :P

Answer (score 1):

If your concern is just about the space not being preserved,

Replace

`if (character >='a' && character <='z'){`

with

`if ((character >='a' && character <='z') || character == ' '){`

Comment: It gets rid of the space even when I did that..:/

Comment: @VHS you didn't take into account that the original input character was "shifted" before the conditionals. See Murat's answer.

Comment: @walen, yes. You are right. Looks like the OP has already accepted Murat's answer.

Comment: Thank you! I kept doing this ' ' instead of '  ' and getting an error. Silly mistake all sorted.

Answer (score 0):

Add a condition for the space character in for loop and continue.

for (int i=0; i<text.length();i++){

```
   char c=text.charAt(i);

   if( c== ' '){
       newMsg+=c;
       continue;
    }
  ......
```

}